# Problema al correr app en react native

Tags: react-native

TENGO ESTE ERROR AL CORRER REACT-NATIVE RUN-IOS

Failed to install the requested application
The bundle identifier of the application could not be determined.
Ensure that the application's Info.plist contains a value for CFBundleIdentifier

Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

AL VOLVER A EJECUTAR EL COMANDO ME MANDA ESTE ERROR

A ALGUIEN LE AH PASADO & ¿COMO LO HAN SOLUCIONADO?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola amigo espero ya lo hayas solucionado si no te recomiendo que sigas los pasos que dicen en el error 
`watchman-del-all && rm -rf node_modules && npm install` ... etc.

Comment: Si, espere a que se corrigieran los problemas con actualizaciones ya que estaba manejando versiones beta